# How can I know which button I clicked to start an action inside the program?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have 3 buttons which call the same function. I want to know inside the function which button called it. Is it possible to know it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `sender` argument. If you have an IBOutlet called `buttonOne`, you can check inside the IBAction method like this:

```
- (IBAction) buttonClicked:(id) sender
{
    if (sender == buttonOne)
    {
        NSLog(@"Button one was pressed.");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, assign each of your buttons a `tag`, and use the sender's `tag` property (the following example assumes that `buttonOne` was assigned the tag value “1”):

```
- (IBAction) buttonClicked:(id) sender
{
    if ([sender tag] == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Button one was pressed.");
    }
}
```